# Linguistics Community FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq

## (Under construction!)

You may also wish to review [the community FAQ for all sites in the StackExchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

### Content

### About the site

- [Do you hold regular chat events?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/111)
- [How can we promote Linguistics StackExchange?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/326/111) See also [Promoting the site (old topic)](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/216/111)
- [What is this Community Bulletin?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/111)
- [Linguistics Terminology](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/387/111)
- [Can I propose a change in the FAQ?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/392/111)
- [How should we treat new users?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/449/111)

### Asking questions

- [What are the various fields that belong to Linguistics?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/111)
- [What is considered on-topic and off-topic?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/111)
- Should we restrict this site to academic questions only, or target a more casual audience?
- Do questions have to be answerable?

### Answering questions

- Should answers be cited? How?
- Should this site be restricted to academic answers only?
- [Should I post a new answer to a question that already has an accepted answer?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/111)

### Accepting answers

- What are the criteria for marking an answer correct?
- [Can I change my accepted answer?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/377/111)
- My answer was marked correct, now the OP changed it and chose another one: what's happening?
- Is it important that I accept an answer also in the Meta site? Why?
- [What is the acceptance rate for questions?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/408/111)

### Working with posts

- I've got edit privileges! Now what?

### Comments

- [How to handle discussions?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/379/111)
- Why was my comment deleted?

### Tagging

- How should we tag questions?

### Reputation, badges, and voting

- What is reputation and what is it for?
- Why was my question down-voted in Meta if nothing was wrong with it?
- [What are badges and why do we have them?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges)
- What should I do if a badge was awarded to me by a bug?

### Moderation

- [Who are the moderators?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/375/111) See also [Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/200/111)
- [I'm not a moderator, what does it mean to vote to close a question?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/248/111)
- [My question was closed, in my opinion wrongly. What do I do?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/111)

### External links

Original links from meta.SO's community FAQ for sites in the StackExchange 2.0 network:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [How to Ask by Jon Skeet](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)
- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Rubber Duck problem solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

---

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:

  `[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)`
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems to hit a mature state, flag it for moderator attention, choose **other** then write why you're flagging, and it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
- Add a link in the above table of contents.
- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body. The answer goes in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is still under construction, you can add the questions yourself. Remember to read the "How can a question be added to this FAQ?" section in the question above about how to do it.