# FAQ: What is this Community Bulletin?

Tags: discussion, faq

What is this yellow box on the right side of the site? How does it work?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Community Bulletin]

A recent meta question on MSO, [Nailing it up on your Community Bulletin Board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130892/176533), presented the new feature. It's a moderator-only feature that allows us to share events, or meta posts in the Main site *and* the Meta site.

Pay attention to it from now on, as every important news will be shared there! :) The part on the side will let you know what type of event it is: in the example above, it's a meta question. If it's an event, you'll see *event* written on the side.