# FAQ: Do you hold regular chat events?

Tags: discussion, faq, chat-events

Some SE sites hold regular events on different topics, so I was wondering:

- does Linguistics have chat events?
- Are they regular?
- When is the next one?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting May 2012, the Linguistics site will hold chat events. They are held regularly every month, roughly by the end of the month (from the 25th to the 30th day). Information on the next Linguistics meeting can be found [here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/111).

You can find the saved transcripts below:

- [#1 Linguistics Meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/conversation/1-linguistics-meeting) (May 27th 2012)
- [#2 Linguistics Meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/conversation/2-linguistics-meeting) (June 30th 2012)
- [#3 Linguistics Meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/conversation/3-linguistics-meeting) (July 28th 2012)
- [#4 Linguistics Meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/conversation/4-linguistics-meeting) (August 25th 2012)
- ## 5 Linguistics Meeting **[[check discussion](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/111)]**