# What is the acceptance rate for questions?

Tags: support, faq

I've noticed that the acceptance rate for my questions has gone down.   What is the acceptance rate?   How does it affect my reputation, privileges, or badges?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **acceptance rate** is calculated on the answers you accepted in your questions, related to the total number of questions you asked.

For example, if you ask 10 questions and accept 9, you'll have a 90% accept rate. *Simple, no?*

Note that the acceptance rate starts only after the 5th question. If you ask 4 questions, the acceptance rate is not shown.

Lastly, the acceptance rate **does not affect reputation** (well, apart from the fact that when you accept an answer you get +2 reputation) or badges or privileges. Privileges are given according to reputation, and badges encourage good behavior.